# What kind of requests do e-mail clients send when retrieving e-mails?

Tags: rest, amazon-s3, websocket, aws-api-gateway, imap

I am working on an IMAP implementation using AWS API gateways in which I have to retrieve e-mails from a S3-bucket and get them into an e-mail client somehow, but I've not been able to find which requests those clients send when you try to retrieve e-mails from another source. My guess is GET-requests, but I'm honestly not even sure if it's REST-requests that are being sent. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to manually implement the [IMAP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) in an API Gateway? Have you looked at SES instead?

Comment: And obviously no, it is not regular GET requests and not remotely close to REST. GET is an HTTP protocol related term, you are looking at a different protocol that has no concept of such a thing.

Comment: @luk2302 I have actually looked at SES. The thing is that SES doesn't implement IMAP, so there's not really a way that I could get the e-mails from there into my own e-mail client. That's why I'm trying to make my own implementation. Do you perhaps have any idea which requests are being sent?

Comment: Look at the wikipedia link and go from there. Outlining the entire implementation of a protocol is outside the scope of a comment or even an answer on SO. I would be surprised if API Gateway can help you there since it is primarily focused on http(s) and wss, you cannot just use any protocol you want with it. Maybe AWS WorkMail can help.

Comment: @luk2302 I'll be looking into AWS WorkMail and the Wikipedia page then, thanks for your fast responses!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.